# Jquery click-event stop working after reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append, event-listener

I'm working on a small calculator. It has numbers from 1 to 10, a reset button and one submit button. One click-event on the numbers and one on each of reset and submit. It works so far, one pick 5 numbers and hit Submit and it shows the number you have chosen and the total value. So far so god. But when you hit reset to calculate the next 5 numbers and start to pick new numbers, the click-event doesn't fire. The Calculator is dead until you refresh the browser, then it works again.
I use JQuery 3.2.1

Here is the code...I show only 3 buttons )

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";
  var nrArray = [];
  var sum = 0;
       
  $(".nrKnappar").click(function(){
    var nummer = parseInt($(this).val(),10);
    nrArray.push(nummer);

    if(nrArray.length <= 5){ 
      $("#resultat p").append("<span> " + nummer + "</span>");  
    }/*if*/
   });/*click nrKnappar*/ 
  
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    $.each( nrArray, function( key, value ) {
       sum += value;
    });
   $("#total").append("<p>" + sum + "</p>");
     $("#submit").prop("disabled", true);
  }); /*submit*/
  
   $("#reset").click(function(){
     $("#resultat p span").remove();
    $("#total p").remove();
    $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
  });
  
}); /*document ready*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="skottcounter">
  <button class="nrKnappar" id="ett" name="ett" value="1">1</button>
  <button class="nrKnappar" id="tva" name="tva" value="2">2</button>
  <button class="nrKnappar" id="tre" name="tre" value="3">3</button>
  <br>
</div>
<div id="resultat">
  <p></p>
</div> 
<div id="total"></div>
```

So the question is, why does the eventlistener stop working? I get no errors in the consol in FF or Chrome. The reset button only remove the resultat and totalt and enable the submit button again, it never touch the number pad. (I thought that anyway)
//L

Comment: Can you add the full code with the reset button? This will be very helpful.

Comment: You have multiple syntactical errors in your code eg if(nrArray.length  " + nummer + "");

Comment: Where is the reset button?